# ESP8266WebServer.h, "functional: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, arduino, iot

I tried to install library ESP8266WebServer into platformio IDE.
I got this error "functional: No such file or directory". A bit of research of "functional", http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/

```
In file included from configMode.cpp:13:0:
.pioenvs/uno/ESP8266WebServer/ESP8266WebServer.h:27:22: fatal error: functional: No such file or directory
#include <functional>
^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, with the same class on https://create.arduino.cc/editor

Comment: Check the include path that the compiler is using.

Comment: Is there any progress in solution this problem ?

Comment: I think I use vim instead at the end.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the very same error happened when I was trying to

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
```

in a **.c** file.

It should be **.cpp** in order to compile without errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but realised I had the wrong board set in the Arduino IDE. If you haven't installed the Arduino core for ESP8266 (https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino#installing-with-boards-manager) do so, then select the correct board from the Arduino IDE Tools menu.

I now have other compiler errors though.